# table (with divs) converts to accordion on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there a way to write a media query such that a table of divs converts into an accordion when the screen resizes to a mobile size?

In other words, on desktop / tablet screen sizes, the page show 2-3 divs in full, but on a mobile screen size the divs get nested in an accordion.

Any pointers on this would be really helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: with tables? Probably not. With divs, yes, for sure, but you'll need some JS/Jquery besides CSS for better performance (although it can be done with only CSS)

Comment: @Fabio Thank you. Do you have example code I could refer to that might help in achieving this? do you know if you've seen such an example somewhere?